# Import Civil 3D DEM to ArcMap or QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcmap, dem, civil3d

I have some survey data exported from Civil 3D in both dtm and dem formats.  I thought the I would be able to use the dem more easily, but I think the format is different from a USGS DEM.  Is it possible to use this data in either ArcMap or QGIS?  I'm using QGIS for raster analysis with the GRASS plugin as I don't have the 3D Analyst extension.

Thanks for any help!

---

@johanvdw Thanks guys, here it is.  Starts with 'Autodesk Export Surface2DEM'  then

{1     2   405   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00   0.000000000000000D+00     1     1     4   0.585166731876923D+07   0.212104288166666D+07   0.585166731876923D+07   0.212938888166666D+07 }

Comment: Try posting the first lines of the DEM file here, it will give an idea which procedure you can use to load the file.

Comment: @johanvdw- I'm actually able to open the DEM in ArcMap, and have tried to convert it to a Geotiff to use in QGIS but that hasn't worked.  I'm unable to open directly in QGIS. Sorry, I'm not sure how to post the lines, can you advise?

Comment: open the file with a text-editor such as notepad

Comment: try to open with notepad or wordpad, and copy just a few of the top lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Civil3d (2010+), you can choose GeoTiff as an export option, then load into QGIS (1.8) as a regular old raster, create a hillshade etc.

They make you choose this in the 'Dem file name' option in the export surface dialog so it's not immediately obvious where to change formats.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @WolfOdrade- This is really useful, thanks.  The file was exported by someone else so I'll see if they can send me a geotiff.

Answer (score 1):

In Autocad Civil there's no .DTM format, sir, only a .TIN one.

You can easily convert a C3D surface to Dem (readable by Qgis) by means of the **_SurfaceExportToDem** command.

:)

Comment: The file was exported by someone else for my use so I'm not sure what process they used.  It just seemed that the DEM may need conversion or some processing as I was having trouble getting it to load or render.